# When we are creating datasets in our org in to waveanalytics they are continously dataflow is getting failed. Can anybody tell how to resolve it

Tags: analytics, einstein-analytics

Recently I added wave analytics to our org with setting all permission license and permission set and it is enabled.But when we are creating data sets in wave then data flow is getting failed. How to resolve it can anybody tell it helpful for me.

Error we are getting is:

> There was an error executing the 101 node: Field [BussinessUnit__c] is not available. Verify that the field exists and that the Analytics Cloud Integration User profile has Read level access on the field.

And one more thing is that if are creating data set without "[BussinessUnit__c]" then also it is showing same error.

Answer (score 0):

One idea - If you have the correct permissions applied to the fields.. I would check whether that field actually has data in it..

You can check this via https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php

If there is no data in the field, remove it from your dataflow.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

check if you have permission to required field in 
profile

> Analytics Cloud Integration User

even after that issue persists then you need to create a dataflow from the scratch as of my criteria i did the same even after i gave the permission it did not recognize it hence made the dataflow again